# Pure custom simple TABLE in material design, any idea? | **Note : Without using any third library or js

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Something like a simple structure with default material design, as i am working with angular + material:

```
<table>
 <tr>

  <td></td>
  <td></td>

 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: "Without using any third party library or js" makes little sense to me when you're talking about angularJS.

Comment: It's just simple what i am saying is that, i have to make table without using any other js just like i.e mdDataTable

Comment: I appreciate what you meant, but angularjs _is_ a third party javascript framework. You will need to elaborate on what it is you wish to accomplish. So far, all I can discern is that you wish to create a table using angularJS.

Comment: Yes you are right, and thanks for the response BTW

Comment: You mean you just want to use CSS?

Comment: Actually not at all, but there should something can we make our own directives kind of thing.

Comment: Provide an example controller, and ideally a view you that you have created to demonstrate what you have tried thus far

Comment: I haven't did anything on this yet, as i have asked this question for get guideline, i want to confirm that is this exists or something other ways will get this done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Either with an angular view or with a directive. In many cases, a combination of the two are used. AngularJS provides a mechanism for two way data binding. There are several ways in which you could display a table using angularJS. Here is two of the most basic ways to display a table using an angular view/controller.

N.B. This does not provide two-way data binding. `ng-model` would have to be included to use that.

**Example Controller**

```
var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('exampleCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) 
   $scope.exampleOne = 'Display me!';
   $scope.exampleTwo = [
                        {'name': 'Daniel', 'country: 'United Kingdom'},
                        {'name': 'Robert', 'country': 'Norway'}
                       ];
}]);
```

**View**

```
<div ng-controller="exampleCtrl">
    <table> <!-- Example One -->
     <tr>
      <td>{{exampleOne}}</td>        
     </tr>
    </table>
    <table> <!-- Example Two -->
     <tr ng-repeat="info in exampleTwo">
       <td>{{info.name}}</td>
       <td>{{info.country}}</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Output**

```
<div ng-controller="exampleCtrl">
    <table> <!-- Example One -->
     <tr>
      <td>Display me!</td>        
     </tr>
    </table>
    <table> <!-- Example Two -->
     <tr>
       <td>Daniel</td>
       <td>United Kingdom</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Robert</td>
       <td>Norway</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes i actually already knew this, like from this way we can populate table, thanks for your efforts appreciate that, but this will no longer prove as useful.

Comment: Then I truly have no idea what it is you're asking :)

Comment: you are right  Daniel, but this technique i knew and you are right actually, i have up voted it that's why. But i was talking about my given answer like that.

Answer (score -1):

Make custom directory with table like :

```
<custom-table>
  <cth>
    <ctd></ctd>
  </cth>
  <ctr>
   <ctd></ctd>
  </ctr>
</custom-table>
```