# How to iterate data in different tr in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular js .I want to iterate the below json in different tr. Currently i am getting the data in a single row by using ng-repeat.Is there is any by which i can set the data in different rows

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "project": "wewe2012",
    "date": "2013-02-26",
    "description": "ewew",
}

Required Output:
<tr>
 <td>Emp id</td>
  <td>Emp id</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Project</td>
  <td>wewe2012</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>date</td>
  <td>2013-02-26/td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>description</td>
  <td>ewew</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Post what you have already done

Comment: You don't need to use `ng-repeat` when your object literal does not contain more than one item?

Comment: You **_ITERATE_** on a Collection/Array. Your data is none of them.

Comment: @DanielShillcock: My data  would always be a single object.How can i iterate without using ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use `ng-repeat` as you are not iterating over an object literal structure. As long as your view is bound to your controller, you can do the following. For the purposes of this example, I will assume your object is called `exampleObject`.

Note: If your object literal was an array of structures, you could use `ng-repeat` and iterate over the object to produce a view, however in this case, it is not necessary.

There is a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40172912/pure-custom-simple-table-in-material-design-any-idea-note-without-using) explaining how to iterate over an object to create a table.

**Object**

```
var exampleObject = {
    "id": 2,
    "project": "wewe2012",
    "date": "2013-02-26",
    "description": "ewew",
}
```

**View**

```
<tr>
 <td>Emp id</td>
  <td>{{exampleObject.id}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Project</td>
  <td>{{exampleObject.project}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>date</td>
  <td>{{exampleObject.date}}/td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>description</td>
  <td>{{exampleObject.description}}/td>
</tr>
```